# Suggested actions are not working in teams when I'm using bot composer to create my bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Suggested Actions feature is working fine in teams application when I use bot framework SDK. But when I use **Send a response** in Bot Composer and add the Suggested Actions it doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCxPJ.png)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding, we did try this by following the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/quickstart-create-bot. It is working fine at our end, could you please let us know if you have done it differently? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z80rE.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPmMJ.png